# Как добавить в панораму Яндекс карты раскрывающийся список

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Помогите разобраться, вот пример моего кода:

```
// Отображаем панораму на странице.
window.yPlayer = new ymaps.panorama.Player('pano-area', panorama, {
    direction: [25, 0],
    controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl'],
});
var myListBox = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
    data: {
        content: '2019'
    },
    items: [
        new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem('2018'),
        new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem('2017'),
    ]
});

yPlayer.controls.add(myListBox);
```

Comment: Задайте, пожалуйста, вопрос более развёрнуто, что именно вам непонятно в коде, тогда легче будет вам помочь.

Comment: У меня появляется ошибка "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" и собственно список на панораме не появляется.